# Network drive on mac - files are all read-only

Tags: macos, networking

I have connected (on a Mac) to a network drive set up by a friend in an attempt to set up a shared web drive/Mercurial version control environment, and have access to all files correctly.

However, they seem to be all read-only (which is unfortunate as I need to modify the code in them) and I do not seem to be able to change the permissions.

At no point in the setting up process I remember an option to make (or un-make) files read-only and I have no idea how to move on from this impasse. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the username/password you used to set up the network drive is only having Read Only access on the files? This is a permission issue and most likely due to the username used to connect has no write access. Might want to check the setting of the network drive (write power for the user, or use a different username that has write access)

Comment: Thank you Darius - the user I am actually connecting with is (I was asked for a user/pw when setting up the drive) is the usual FTP authentication: we have only one so I wouldn't think that would have lower privileges.

Comment: Found the issue. From the Finder, I can connect to FTP servers only with read-only access. 

Guess that closes the deal :)

Comment: Can you connect to the network drive using different protocol? SMB / AFP ?

Comment: Sadly not - tried both of them and they wouldn't connect. I am now using a normal FTP editor to check the version and sync - a bit slower, but at least it works. Thank you for the help!